# OpenLayers 5 to 6: Layers not rendering

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

We are trying to migrate our OL5 map to be an OL6 map.  When we use OL6, the map doesn't render at all, and in DevTools if we set a height to the map div the zoom tools and logo show fine, but there are no layers.  We replaced the map with the Quick Start map and it doesn't work in 6, 5 is perfectly fine.  Inspecting our map object shows no issues and is as expected.

Anyone else have any issues or solved this issue, or can help?  Thanks!

HTML Declaration:

```
<div id="ephem-map" class="map-medium"></div>
```

Controller.js:

```
   vm.map = MapFactory.getMapInstance({
            id: 'ephem-map',
            zoomLevel: 2
        });
```

MapFactory:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    /* global ol, angular */

    angular.module('common').factory('MapFactory', MapFactory);

    MapFactory.$inject = [];

    function MapFactory() {

        var factory = {
            getMapInstance: getMapInstance
        };
        return factory;

        function getMapInstance(options) {
            return new _MapConstructor(options);
        }


        function _MapConstructor(options) {
            /**
             * Guarantee "new" instance
             */
            if (!(this instanceof _MapConstructor)) {
                return new _MapConstructor(options);
            }

            options = options || {};
            var _id = options.id || 'map';
            var _zoomLevel = options.zoomLevel || 2;
            var _resultsOptions = options.results || {};
            var _wrapX = options.wrapX || false;
            var _infoTag = options.infoTag || 'info';



            // The actual ol.Map object that manipulates the DOM
            var _map = undefined;

            // Run on construction
            _initialize();

            // The working MapInstance object
            var mapinstance = {};

            return mapinstance;

            function setTarget(target) {
                _map.setTarget(target);
            }

            /**
             * Private Methods to _MapInstance
             */
            function _initialize() {
                _map =  new ol.Map({
                    target: _id,
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            source: new ol.source.OSM()
                        })
                    ],
                    view: new ol.View({
                        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
                        zoom: 4
                    })
                  });
                }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: OL and angularjs are completely unrelated

Comment: I know that.  The examples OL provides work when not in an angular.js framework, but not using the framework, so I was wondering if there was some sort of incompatibility or if it was tested.

Answer (score 3):

Solved this by setting a set height on my map containers.  Seems it no longer renders with only min/max-heights set in css.

Comment: Thanks for posting this solution as its not obvious. As for OpenLayers making this change to cause it to break - seriously WTF?